# Insert into MySQL a huge number of rows, based on subquery... having trouble

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093, mysql-error-1242

So, what I am trying to do is insert a row of NONE, $country for every country that exists in the table.

It should look like

```
   Afghanistan, NONE
   Albania, NONE
   Andorra, None
```

...
That is, in addition to the provinces listed for each country... they look like this:

```
| Zambia                    | Western                                            |
| Zimbabwe                  | Bulawayo                                           |
| Zimbabwe                  | Harare                                             |
| Zimbabwe                  | Manicaland                                         |
| Zimbabwe                  | Mashonaland Central                                |
| Zimbabwe                  | Mashonaland East                                   |
| Zimbabwe                  | Mashonaland West                                   |
| Zimbabwe                  | Masvingo                                           |
| Zimbabwe                  | Matabeleland North                                 |
| Zimbabwe                  | Matabeleland South                                 |
| Zimbabwe                  | Midlands
```

This is the code I am attempting, but failing miserably.

```
insert into countries2 (province,country) 
VALUES ('NONE', (select distinct country from countries2));
```

I just get

`You can't specify target table 'countries2' for update in FROM clause`

But it is also throwing the error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into countries2 (province,country) 
 select distinct 'NONE', country from countries2
```

you may want to check the order of the fields !

Comment: Perfect, distinct 'NONE'. Haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you actually just want to update the existing table here?
Try

```
UPDATE countries2 SET province = 'NONE'
```

Comment: Actually the table contains thousands of entries, I am just trying to add "NONE" to the list of each countries' provinces.